# 8 How to configure add-on products in Commerce 2.x

Tags: 8, commerce

What is the best way in Commerce 2.x to allow the shopper to check boxes to add optional accessories to a product before he adds the product to the cart. In addition, the product price should be updated.

[image: checkboxes to add accessories to product]

Sounds like this module would do it in D7: [Commerce Product Add-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado).

This question asks the same question, but it's tagged with 7. [Can a VBO form be integrated with the Commerce Add-to-Cart form to allow adding optional add-on products with checkboxes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196773/can-a-vbo-form-be-integrated-with-the-commerce-add-to-cart-form-to-allow-adding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commerce Product Add-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) now has a beta release for D8.